# Integrate django and RoR (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, integration

I have a website built by someone else with ruby-on-rails, and I'm now building a django application.

I need my users to sign in with my sign-in page built on django and surf my django pages (so far - easy to do) but I also need to add links on the sidebar to that RoR application (and from there they will be able to come back to my app).

The users shouldn't know that they are "leaving" the django app - **for them its one website** - that RoR app looks and feels the same for them.

***A.*** How can I do this?
***B.*** They sign in with the django app so the sessions and all user stuff will be managed by django. How can I "pass" sessions to the RoR app? Should I use iframe??
***C.*** How do the links in django to the RoR url look like?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice here would be to look to how advertising networks share state across multiple properties. One commonly used method is a tracking pixel. For example, in your Django app, embed:

```
<img src="http://myrailsapp/mysession_creator" />
```

Make sure that your rails app responds at that address with a session. That will establish a session cookie on the rails domain.

Now to layer on security, and it depends on what level of security you need. You could pass in information, like:

```
<img src="http://myrailsapp/mysession_creator?user=myUserName" />
```

Obviously not incredibly secure, but it depends on your app. A more secure method would be:

```
<img src="http://myrailsapp/mysession_creator?t=<MD5HashTokenHere>" />
```

Then the Rails app would have a mechanism of validating that token against the Django app server side (either through database state or a server side application call.) More work, but more secure.

Another method, if your applications share a root domain, you can use a secure cookie on the root domain to pass information between applications. For example, https://django.myapp.com sets a myapp.com cookie, and https://rails.myapp.com knows to look for a "username" cookie. Requires a wildcard SSL cert on the root domain.

Another option is to pass the token or login information with every link to the Rails app, and have a before_filter that recognizes the hand off and establishes the session in a similar way.

Comment: Your first solution works great! Much easier than I expected. Thanks!!!      I want to comment for other readers, although might be obvious, that I realized there is a problem with this <img...> call since it can be used anytime by anyone to start a new session in the rails app without a password! Therefore adding the t parameter (MD5HashTokenHere) is needed with a new and time-limited token.                Thanks again @Joshua - you saved me!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but we did this before using 2 rails apps.

Make sure the session keys in Rails and in your django app are the same.

In Rails, it'll probably look like this:

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_my_session_key',
  :secret      => '_my_session_secret'
}
```

In Django, a quick google led me to this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY

I think once those are the same, the two apps will share the same session.

Comment: Pat, I believe Rails and Django have different session formats and protocols, so they cannot share sessions natively (like two Rails apps might be able to.)